# how to set timeout for: `google-client spreadsheet api`?

Tags: java, google-api, timeout, spreadsheet, httptransportse

I'm using google-client api for spreadsheet.

I get a time out after 20 seconds. How can i set the timeout to a custom value?

```
private Sheets initService(GoogleCredential credential) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("my_app")
            .build();
}
```

should i set it in the `HttpTransport`?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and actually found a documented solution from Google

[Google API Client Libraries - Timeouts and Errors](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors)

And for simplicity your implementation must add a call to:

```
.setHttpRequestInitializer(createHttpRequestInitializer(credential))
```

In the Sheets.Builder and then add the following method to your class, provide any timeout values seems reasonable for the application.

```
    private HttpRequestInitializer createHttpRequestInitializer(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
    return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(final HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
            httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000); // 3 minutes connect timeout
            httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000); // 3 minutes read timeout
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: On python I just increased the amount of retries to `10` instead of the default `1` as a quick solution which seemed to have resolved my connection errors on a slower connection. ```service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials, num_retries=10) sheet = service.spreadsheets()```

Answer (score -1):

```
private Sheets initService(GoogleCredential credential) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, setTimeout(credential, 60000))
        .setApplicationName("my_app")
        .build();
}

private HttpRequestInitializer setTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer initializer, final int timeout) {
    return request -> {
        initializer.initialize(request);
        request.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    };
}
```